# Validation of a dynamic form that can add or remove fields

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a form that can have fields added and deleted.
I built the form from a tutorial I found and it works perfectly except if you forget to complete one of the fields. the PHP checking works, ie my data base does not get filled with a load of blank values but to the user it looks as if it has all gone through.

I have been trying to validate my form with javascript and have tried a couple of ways but my knowledge of JS is limited and i am struggling.

This is the code that I've written so far:

```js
function validateForm() {
  if (document.getElementById$(this).attr("id").validity.valueMissing) {
   alert("Please complete all of the fields");
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){  
  var i=1;  
  $('#add').click(function(){  
    i++;  
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="date" name="date[]" id="date'+i+'" required /></td><td><textarea rows="6" cols="50" name="name[]" id="name'+i+'" placeholder="Enter the training session" required ></textarea></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
  });  
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
       var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
       $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
  });  
  $('#submit').click(function(){           
       $.ajax({  

            method:"POST",  
            data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
            success:function(data){  
                 alert(data);  
                 $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
            }
       }); 
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">  
  <form name="add_name" id="add_name" onsubmit="return validateForm()">  
    <div>  
      <table id="dynamic_field">  
        <tr> 
          <td><input type="date" name="date[]" id="date'+i+'" required /></td> 
          <td><textarea rows="6" cols="50" name="name[]" id="name'+i+'" placeholder="Enter the training session" required ></textarea></td>  
          <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add">Add More</button></td>  
        </tr>  
      </table>  
      <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />  
    </div>  
  </form>  
</div>
```

Any suggestion would be very helpful with the form validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made few changes so your code can catch if Date have been selected:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">  
  <form name="add_name" id="add_name" onsubmit="return validateForm()">  
    <div>  
      <table id="dynamic_field">  
        <tr> 
          <td><input type="date" name="date[]" id="date0" required /></td> 
          <td><textarea rows="6" cols="50" name="name[]" id="name0" placeholder="Enter the training session" required ></textarea></td>  
          <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add">Add More</button></td>  
        </tr>  
      </table>  
      <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />  
    </div>  
  </form>  
</div> 




<script>
function validateForm() {
  if (document.getElementById$(this).attr("id").validity.valueMissing) {
   alert("Please complete all of the fields");
  }
}
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var i=1;  
  $('#add').click(function(){  
    i++;  
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="date" name="date[]" id="date'+i+'" required /></td><td><textarea rows="6" cols="50" name="name[]" id="name'+i+'" placeholder="Enter the training session" required ></textarea></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
  });  
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
       var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
       $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
  });  


  $('#submit').click(function(){           

     var isValid = true; 
     for(var c=0; c <  i; c++)
       { 
          if ($('#date'+c).val()=='')
       { 
       alert('Please choose date') ;
       $('#date'+c).css({'border' : '1px solid red'});
        isValid = 0; 
       }  
       else 
       { $('#date'+c).css({'border' : '1px solid black'}); }  



       }  // end for   

       if(isValid) { doSave() }

  });  
});  


function doSave() { 
  $.ajax({  

            method:"POST",  
            data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
            success:function(data){  
                 alert(data);  
                 $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
            }
       }); 

}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly and was exactly what i was looking for.